I am making a project and an error of matplotlob library is occuring
Exception has occurred: ImportError
DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
File "C:\Users\KTC\Desktop\Car price\Car Price Prediction.py", line 4, in 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
I was creating car price prediction project and all libraries were installed but this error occured

This question is similar to: matplotlib ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

the error is due to lack of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package on your system.
run this code in terminal:
pip install msvc-runtime

In addition you can check official Microsoft website :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist
